# how to test mfc dialog project by cppunit

Tags: mfc, cppunit

I have 2 projects, one is MFC project, it compiled output type is EXE dialog, the other is a CppUnit project in order to test the MFC project.

I create the Cppunit project as windows Console Project with MFC headers and set up the Cppunit environment, because of MFC project output type is Exe, so I change the project form Exe to lib for test, and add the MFC project's headers in Cppunit project, create an instance from MFC project, then call some functions to test.

but the question is the Cppunit and MFC project all have "theApp" instance, this 2 theApp can't build in Cppunit project.

how to avoid this problem to build success? 
is the Cppunit can test the type of project?

Comment: Hi @stackmetro, could you please edit your question to make it more clear?

Answer (score 0):

I have a sligtly different way to do it. See if it works.

You better create test project with in the solution it self.

**Right click solution->Add->NewProject**

Select under **Test->Native Unit Test Project**.

This way you will see your test project as a DLL and no additional APP object.

**How to refer your MFC dialog in test project?**

Under test project, you will see a References directory, Right click it and select **Add Reference**. You will notice your MFC dialog application and select it.

Now you can add any dialog related header files in your test project and start writing test methods.

**How to run test methods?**

From the menu items of Visual Studio, select **Test->Windows->Test Explorer**.

All your test methods will appear, you can test a specific one or all at a time